# R: Estimating model variance

Tags: r, model, variance

In the demo for ROC, there are models that when plotted have a spread, like hiv.svm$predictions which contains 10 estimates of response.  Can someone remind me how to calculate N estimates of a model.  I'm using RPART and neural network to estimate a single output (true/false).  How can I run 10 different sampling for training data to get 10 different model responses to the input.  I think the function is called bootstraping, but I don't know how to implement it.

I need to do this outside of caret, cause when I use caret I keep getting the message "Error in tab[1:m, 1:m] : subscript out of bounds".  Is there a "simple" bootstrap function?

Comment: Have you done any searching at all?

Comment: Look at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bootstrap/bootstrap.pdf

Comment: For trees, use forest, ref https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-September/140716.html

Comment: @BondedDust I think the problem is that the data to be predicted is rare events, i.e. 10 events in 7000 samples.  Possibly, when caret does bootstrap, all the events get lost, so there is nothing to predict, and the output vector is all zeros.

Comment: Yes. I'm not a user of that package but you should investigate whether there are `caret`-mechanisms for under-sampling the non-event cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously the answer is too late, but you could have used caret just by simply renaming the levels of your factor, because caret doesn't work if your binary response is of type *logical*. For example:

```
factor(responseWithTrueFalseLevel,
       levels=c(TRUE,FALSE),
       labels=c("myTrueLevel","myFalseLevel"))
```